# Error C2589 on std::numeric_limits<double>::min()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, compiler-errors

When I try to compile some code (not my own) i get a C2589 '(':illegal token on right side of'::'

on this line:

```
    maxPosition[0]=std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
```

i guess this is because there is already a min() macro defined, but why is the compiler not taking the min() from the specified namespace instead of the macro?

Comment: do you have #include <limits> ?

Comment: Even though this question is older and I've voted to close as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904635, it might be a candidate for merging as the answers there are more comprehensive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning C4003 and errors C2589 and C2059 on: x = std::numeric\_limits<int>::max();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904635/warning-c4003-and-errors-c2589-and-c2059-on-x-stdnumeric-limitsintmax)

Answer (score 8):

> but why is the compiler not taking the min() from the specified namespace instead of the macro?

Because macros *don't care* about your namespaces, language semantics, or your compiler. The preprocessing happens **first**.

In other words, the compiler only sees what is left after the preprocessing stage. And `min` was replaced by some replacement string, and the result is what the compiler saw.

Answer (score 5):

Hitting F12 on offending std::numeric_limits::min() function

Leads to some where *like* :

c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\minwindef.h

Where you will find:

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX

#ifndef max
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
```

So adding

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

to top of your .cpp file (as the WINAPI does: see Windows.h as example) before any #include headers should rectify the problem.

Comment: This is the best answer to me.

Comment: This should be labeled as the correct answer.
On a side note, this did indeed drive me a bit insane.

Comment: Every two years or so I'm back to this page... just to be reminded that the windows api headers pollute a lot of macros.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the top of your file. I'm pretty sure it's just a bug in the way the linker works in Visual studio. You sometimes get this whenever you have an operator overload.

```
using namespace std;
```

in my case this works

```
 for (int i = min(size_used_, other.size_used_) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  result += data_[i] * other.data_[i];
}
```

when this does not

```
 for (int i = std::min(size_used_, other.size_used_) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  result += data_[i] * other.data_[i];
}
```