# template function specialization default argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++, templates, specialization, visual-c++-2010

```
template <typename T> void function(T arg1, 
    T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(),
    T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max())
{
}

template <> void function<int>(int arg1, int min,int max)
{
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    function<int>(1);
}
```

it give syntax error C2689 and C2059 on function default argument line on `::` token. 
but without specialization, it doing fine. and if I change default argument
and still doing specialization:

```
template <typename T> void function(T arg1, 
    T min = T(0),
    T max = T(1))
{
}
template <> void function<int>(int arg1, int min,int max)
{
}
```

the problem gone too.

now if I use it like this: `function<int>(1,2,3);` or `function<float>(1.0f)` its fine, so it seems that if template function is specialized, we must rewrite the default argument when call it?

but on my second case, where i replace `std::numeric_limits<T>::..` with `T(..)` there no syntax error when calling `function<int>(1)`, why is that?

(I'am using Visual Studio 2010 x64)

as original problem is because of bug, the question now changed to **how to workaround it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code; Comeau Online, Intel C++ 11.1, and g++ 4.1.2 compile it successfully.

I would guess that it is a bug in the compiler.  I recently submitted a related, but slightly different [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557653) against the Visual C++ 2010 compiler.

---

As a workaround, you can wrap the calls:

```
template <typename T>
T get_limits_min() { return std::numeric_limits<T>::min(); }

template <typename T>
T get_limits_max() { return std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); }

template <typename T> void function(T arg1, 
    T min = get_limits_min<T>(),
    T max = get_limits_max<T>())
{
}
```

Ugly?  Quite.

---

**I posted the following in response to [the bug you reported on Microsoft Connect:](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/583081/)**

The primary template must have a parameter that has a default argument value. The default argument value must be a member function of a class template not in the global namespace.

The following is minimal code to reproduce:

```
namespace N
{
    template <typename T>
    struct S
    {
        static T g() { return T(); }
    };
}

template <typename T> void f(T = N::S<T>::g()) { }

template <> void f<>(int) { }

int main()
{
    f<int>();
}
```

The compiler emits the following errors, both on the line where the primary template is defined:

```
error C2589: '::' : illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

Interestingly, there is another issue if the class template is in the global namespace. Given the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    static T g() { return T(); }
};

template <typename T> void f(T = ::S<T>::g()) { }

template <> void f<>(int) { }

int main()
{
    f<int>();
}
```

The compiler emits the following error on the line on which the primary template is defined:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

Both of these example test cases are well-formed C++ programs.

Comment: how do I report this bug to microsoft?

Comment: @uray:  You can submit it at connect.microsoft.com via that bug report link I listed; you'll have to sign in and open a new defect.  If you don't want to, I'll try to reduce this issue and the issue I reported previously to a common sample and resubmit the issue.  Let me know; I'm happy to help.

Comment: bug is reported at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/583081/

Answer (score 2):

As answered here at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13566433/364084 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443191/364084, this is due to min and max macro defined in windows header. The following code should work by preventing the macro expansion:

```
template <typename T> void function(T arg1, 
    T min = (std::numeric_limits<T>::min)(),
    T max = (std::numeric_limits<T>::max)())
{
}

template <> void function<int>(int arg1, int min,int max)
{
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    function<int>(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is succeesfully compiled...
in 
    Comeau Online ,http://codepad.org,EDG Compiler ,and G++ .