# Syntax error with std::numeric_limits::max

Tags: c++, visual-c++, syntax, syntax-error, numeric-limits

I have class struct definition as follows:

```
#include <limits>

struct heapStatsFilters
{
    heapStatsFilters(size_t minValue_ = 0, size_t maxValue_ = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())
    { 
         minMax[0] = minValue_; minMax[1] = maxValue_; 
    }

    size_t minMax[2];
};
```

The problem is that I cannot use 'std::numeric_limits::max()' and the compiler says:

`Error  8   error C2059: syntax error : '::'`

`Error  7   error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'`

The compiler which I am using is Visual C++ 11 (2012)

Comment: Can't reproduce. Try including `<cstddef>`.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae I am not using std for size_t in my code. Should I do that?

Comment: @remyabel Which compiler are you using? I am using Visual C++ 11 (2012)

Comment: check if you have somewhere `#define max(a,b)` or similar, or add `#undef max` before `struct ifxHeapStatsFilters` to check if it's the issue here

Comment: @PiotrS. yes! you are right! it worked! :)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the `<Windows.h>` header file that includes macro definitions named `max` and `min`:

```
#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

Seeing this definition, the preprocessor replaces the `max` identifier in the expression:

```
std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()
```

by the macro definition, eventually leading to invalid syntax:

```
std::numeric_limits<size_t>::(((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

reported in the compiler error: `'(' : illegal token on right side of '::'`.

As a workaround, you can add the `NOMINMAX` define to compiler flags (or to the translation unit, before including the header):

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

or wrap the call to `max` with parenthesis, which prevents the macro expansion:

```
size_t maxValue_ = (std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max)()
//                 ^                                ^
```

or `#undef max` before calling `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`:

```
#undef max
...
size_t maxValue_ = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()
```

Comment: Be warned: defining `NOMINMAX` might cause new trouble as the min/max macros are required/used/expected by lots of other Windows headers...

Comment: <<  or wrap the call to max with parenthesis, which prevents the macro expansion: >> 
Worked perfectly for me, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

As other people say the problem is that in `<WinDefs.h>` (included by `<windows.h>`) is defined macroses `min` and `max`, but if you'll see it's declaration:

```
// <WinDefs.h>
#ifndef NOMINMAX

#ifndef max
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#endif  /* NOMINMAX */
```

you'll see that if there is defined a macro `NOMINMAX` then `WinDefs.h` will not produce these macroses.

That's why it would be better to add a define `NOMINMAX` to project.