# Why won't this template expression compile in MSVC 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

MSVC 2015 chokes on the following statement:

```
if (result > std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max())
{
    ...
}
```

with this error:

```
error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
```

Any idea why?

(I suspected it's an unimplemented C++11 feature and checked [C++11 feature support for MSVC 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), but have not found anything to indicate this).

**EDIT**

I'm trying to compile [`libosmium`](https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium), which is a header-only library that makes heavy use of C++11 templating features. The above error occurs in `osmium/osm/location.hpp`. If I include this header file in `main.cpp`, with no other includes, it compiles without issues. If the header file is included via other headers, the error occurs.

Comment: Most likely you forgot to `#include` the header file that defines `int32_t`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://rextester.com/CXJ86301

Comment: Just checked, the code includes `<cstdint>`

Comment: I think it's `<limits>`

Comment: Thanks! Just tried @P0W's example in my setup, and it compiles fine for me as well; the error must be caused by something else...

Comment: P0W's code compiles here, but if `#include <windows.h>`, then I also get errors (not the same as you though): I get `1>main.cpp(14): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'max'
1>main.cpp(14): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>main.cpp(14): error C2059: syntax error: '::'
1>main.cpp(15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'`, line 14 beeing the line with `max`.

Comment: Refering to my previous comment: If I put `#undef max` after `#include <windows.h>` it compiles fine.

Comment: [Syntax error with std::numeric_limits::max](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27442885/3953764)

Comment: Yes, `windows.h` is the culprit -- and undefining `max` did indeed fix this particular error. Thanks everyone!

Comment: And, yes, there are other issues ... the root problem is that I'm compiling a library that was never intended for Windows.