# Preprocessor macro overriding function definition in c++

Tags: c++, function, overloading, precompiler

I am fairly familiar with the basics of C++, but lack experience (mainly code in Java), so slightly "dumbed down" replies would be appreciated :)

I am extending a larger open source project, which uses a standard visual studio class limits.h, where the following code can be found:

```
template<> class numeric_limits<double>
    : public _Num_float_base
    {   // limits for type double
public:
    typedef double _Ty;

    static _Ty (max)() _THROW0()
    {   // return maximum value
        return (DBL_MAX);
    }
```

I have now imported another open source project, which uses minwindef.h which has this piece of code in it:

```
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
```

The build now breaks because for this line

```
SUMOReal distance = std::numeric_limits<SUMOReal>::max();
```

the compiler complains about max() being used without any parameters.
Is there any quick way to get around this issue, or can I simply not use the library I imported? :/

Hope this was clear enough, thanks for any suggestions!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning C4003 and errors C2589 and C2059 on: x = std::numeric\_limits<int>::max();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904635/warning-c4003-and-errors-c2589-and-c2059-on-x-stdnumeric-limitsintmax)

Comment: An that, my friend, is why macros should not be used, and if used should have horrible names that show their horrible nature

Comment: header files which `#define` `min` or `max` are a sin and should **never be used**.

Comment: @Walter Agreed.  That's why you always compile with `/DNOMINMAX` under Windows.  (The macros are a historical artifact, which are still there to avoid breaking legacy code which used them.  You shouldn't use them in new code.)

Comment: @jrok Yup, definitely duplicate. Looks like I was searching for the wrong things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your compiler settings, have `NOMINMAX` be defined. This will stop the Windows headers from trying to define the `min` and `max` macros. This is the correct way to handle this issue; trying to `#undef` it is unreliable and error-prone. Search for `NOMINMAX` for more information on this flag.

You can also do this in a pinch, but don't make it a habit:

```
SUMOReal distance = (std::numeric_limits<SUMOReal>::max)();
```

Comment: @Walter: Easy to forget, easy to misplace, and unnecessary overhead to write every time when a single top-level define will do.

Comment: Just for the record, if you're using VS, that goes in the property pages, under Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor; just add it to the Preprocessor Definitions field.

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't use VS, but came across such macro definitions elsewhere. They can be very annoying, in particular as the resulting compiler error message make absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Walter I know what you mean: I can remember when `<X11.h>` defined a macro `String`.  Made compiling with USL very painful.  Today, if a library defines such macros for other than historical reasons, and without a documented means of turning them off, I'd say just don't use it.  But that's not the case here: the header in question is a Windows header, and Microsoft documents exactly what you should do to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get around the problem is to `#undef` the macro.

This is one of the reasons that macros traditionally are spelled with all UPPER_CASE letter, while system and standard functions are all lower case.

Comment: The macro is conditionally defined in a Windows header.  It's sufficient to compile with the correct options for it to disappear.

Comment: @JamesKanze I strongly disagree. Going into the details of header files which are recursively `#included` by other header files cannot be sensible. `#undef`ing the macro is perfectly okay.

Comment: I have to agree with @Walter and this answer.

Comment: @Walter It's the `#undef` solution which requires going into the details of the header files (do I need it, etc.).  Just set the correct compiler flags (as documented by Microsoft), and it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent C++ preprocessor for expansion of `max` macro for the specific line of code and then reenable it after the line. This solution would not affect the other parts of code (i.e. if macro `max` is needed somewhere else):

```
#pragma push_macro("max")
#undef max
SUMOReal distance = std::numeric_limits<SUMOReal>::max();
#pragma pop_macro("max")
```

Comment: that is nice. Didn't know that.

Comment: This is pretty neat! Although I chose another answer because it looked like a generally cleaner solution, I don't really want to mess with the general settings of the project too much, so I'll be using this for now. Thanks!

Comment: That is a really nice feature of C++ precompiler